# Trouble with button on iphone?

Tags: html, css

I have this code in my body,

```
<button onclick="change();" id="button2">Click!</button>
```

And this in my css

```
#button2
{
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
}
```

The button appears 200x200 on my computer but appears wrong on my iphone. Why is this? I have used this code before with no problem

Comment: Is the button wrapped in a block-level element?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#button2
{
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
display: block;
}
```